# IdHTTP EIdHTTPProtocolException when using GET

Tags: delphi, indy, idhttp

I am trying to communicate with a Web Relay using the `TIdHTTP.Get()` function.

According to their documentation, each XML response from the Web Relay is 157 bytes long. Below is an example XML response from a WebRelay unit whose input is off, and relay state is on.

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<datavalues>
<relaystate>1</relaystate>
<inputstate>0</inputstate>
<rebootstate>0</rebootstate>
</datavalues>
```

I am getting an `EIdHTTPProtocolException` with `E.ErrorMessage` of `</datavalues>`.

Here is my code:

```pascal
var
  get_url, Response: string;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  IdHTTP.Request.Username := 'admin'; // User
  IdHTTP.Request.Password := 'webrelay'; // Password
  IdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := true; //Auth. BASIC
  try
    get_url := 'http://144.129.139.172 /state.xml';
    response := IdHTTP.Get(get_url);
    Memo1.lines.add(response);
  except
    on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
      Memo2.lines.add(E.ErrorMessage);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Is there really a space in your URL string? URLs don't have spaces in them. In any case, `TIdHTTP.Get()` raises `EIdHTTPProtocolException` when the server reports an HTTP response code indicating an error (ie, anything other than 2xx that is not 101, 3xx redirect, or 401/407 authentication). What is the actual value of `E.ErrorCode` (and `TIdHTTP.ResponseCode`)? Note that you can optionally avoid the `EIdHTTPProtocolException` by enabling the `hoNoProtocolErrorException` and `hoWantProtocolErrorContent` flags in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property.

Comment: I'm new to programming so not sure all you are referring to.  There is no space in string. I get -1 for both E,errorcode and TIdHTTP.ResponseCode

Comment: "*There is no space in string*" - really? You don't see the space between the `2` and `/` characters in the string you provided: `'http://144.129.139.172 /state.xml'`? "*I get -1 for both E.ErrorCode and TIdHTTP.ResponseCode*" - the only way that can happen is if you are not communicating with a valid HTTP server to begin with. Are you SURE the server is using HTTP, and not some other protocol?

Comment: There is a space on my posted version but not in my actual code. It was a transfer error. I know Im communicating because if  enable hoNoProtocolErrorException and hoWantProtocolErrorContent flags I get the return string of </datavalues> which is the last part of what I'm supposed to get. But I dont get the beginning of what I'm supposed to get

Comment: Again, what you describe is simply not possible if the server is following the HTTP 1.x protocol properly. From what you have described, the server is likely just sending the XML by itself, not preceded by any HTTP headers (HTTP 0.9, perhaps?). If so, then `TIdHTTP` is the wrong component to use, try `TIdTCPClient` instead. Can you provide a trace log of the raw TCP data that is being transmitted, such as from a sniffer like Wireshark? Or, from the output of assigning one of Indy's `TIdLog...` components to the `TIdHTTP.Intercept` property? Or, at least, a link to the documentation? Anything?

Comment: Here is log file: Stat Connected.
Sent 9/17/2021 1:03:12 PM: GET /state.xml HTTP/1.1<EOL>Host: 144.129.139.172<EOL>Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8<EOL>User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)<EOL>Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46ODY4NmM5NTI=<EOL><EOL>
Recv 9/17/2021 1:03:12 PM: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><EOL><datavalues><EOL><relaystate>0</relaystate><EOL><inputstate>0</inputstate><EOL><rebootstate>0</rebootstate><EOL><totalreboots>0</totalreboots><EOL></datavalues>
Stat Disconnected.

Comment: As I suspected, the server is NOT using HTTP 1.x for the response.  I have posted an answer describing what you can do to work around this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the log you provided in comments, the Web Relay is NOT using HTTP 1.x for its response, it appears to be using [HTTP 0.9](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html) instead, which [`TIdHTTP` does not currently support](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/91).

It is not uncommon for HTTP servers in the wild to be sensitive to the `User-Agent` request header, delivering different types of data for different web browsers.  Some real-world HTTP servers do not recognize Indy's default `User-Agent` and thus treat their responses oddly, and using HTTP 0.9 to respond to `TIdHTTP` has been observed before (albeit rarely).

So, the first thing you should try is setting the `TIdHTTP.Request.UserAgent` property to a value that mimics a real web browser, eg:

```pascal
var
  get_url, Response: string;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  IdHTTP.Request.Username := 'admin'; // User
  IdHTTP.Request.Password := 'webrelay'; // Password
  IdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := true; //Auth. BASIC

  // ADD THIS (use whatever UA you want, as long as it is real)...
  IdHTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0';

  try
    get_url := 'http://144.129.139.172/state.xml';
    Response := IdHTTP.Get(get_url);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Response);
  except
    on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
      Memo2.Lines.Add(E.ErrorMessage);
  end;
end;
```

If that does not work to make the Web Relay respond using HTTP 1.x, then you should contact the Web Relay's admins for help.  If the Web Relay cannot be made to respond using HTTP 1.x, you will simply not be able to use `TIdHTTP` for communicating with it, period.  In which case, you will have to use `TIdTCPClient` instead, sending your own HTTP request so you can then read the entire XML, eg:

```pascal
var
  Response: string;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  try
    IdTCPClient1.Host := '144.129.139.172';
    IdTCPClient1.Port := 80;
    IdTCPClient1.Connect;
    try
      with IdTCPClient1.IOHandler do
      begin
        WriteLn('GET /state.xml HTTP/1.0');
        WriteLn('Host: ' + IdTCPClient1.Host);
        WriteLn('Accept: */*');
        WriteLn('User-Agent: ...');
        WriteLn('Authorization: Basic ' + TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString('admin:webrelay', IndyTextEncoding_UTF8));
        WriteLn;

        Response := AllData;
      end;
    finally
      IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;
    end;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Response);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Memo2.Lines.Add(E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and patience. The Client code works perfect.